# Diffrent User registration form for doctor and patient

Tags: customization, user-registration

I am building a health care website. where both patient and doctors are allowed to register.
Here I want to register doctors by different registration form  and should be available with different role. and patient different registration form. and different page . any idea plugin or any code .